# Target elements within an element having a particular ID

Tags: jquery

Let say I have this almost identical code:

```
<div id="the-story" class="tabs-content">
    <div id="panel01" class="content active">
          panel01 content
    </div>
    <div id="panel02" class="content">
          panel02 content
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="tabs" data-tab="">
    <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel01">ONE</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel02">TWO</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my second piece of code:

```
<div id="the-scene" class="tabs-content">
    <div id="panel01" class="content active">
          panel01 content
    </div>
    <div id="panel02" class="content">
          panel02 content
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="tabs" data-tab="">
    <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel01">ONE</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel02">TWO</a></li>
</ul>
```

If these two are on the same page, how do I with jQuery target a specific one?
Or how do I make sure that the function I want to trigger on document ready only affects one of the two?

For example this will affect both:

```
$('.tab-title').removeClass("active");
$('.content').removeClass("active");
```

Can I wrap the two "blocks" of code in a div with a unique ID or?

Comment: Normally you'd use what's called "DOM traversal" to target the appropriate element. What event triggers the function?

Comment: Wrapping the two blocks of code in divs with unique ids seems like a fine solution to this problem.

Comment: If those blocks of code are on the same page then you have a problem because IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

For changing `$('.content')` you can use few selectors:

```
$('#the-story .content').removeClass("active");
```

and

```
$('#the-scene .content').removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

To expound on my comment regarding DOM traversal, here's how it might be done for a tab click:

```
$('.tab-title').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    var tabIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.content').eq(tabIndex).removeClass("active");
});
```

This eliminates the need for ID targeting altogether by targeting the content panel having the same index as the tab.